# How can I find out why my badge is not accepting HTML tags on its tooltip?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a bootstrap badge-alert with an HTML tooltip on it, following the example under: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/tooltips/

However, with the following code, the tooltip is shown, but the HTML tags are not interpreted.

The badge HTML code follows (it is a badge inside a table cell - td):

```html
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<b>Tooltip</b> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>">1</span>
```

I've tried activating the tooltips on the $(document).ready function, as stated on the page, with

```
   // initialize tooltips
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

But still couldn't figure why it is happening.

[image]

I definitely have no idea on why the HTML is not getting formatted, nor how to debug/understand the source of this issue. How would you even start debugging it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing? Is the tooltip work or not?

Comment: Sorry, in fact the HTML tags in the tooltip are not showing correctly: instead of having the formatted text, I have "<b>Tooltip</b>" plain text. I've updated the post, couldn't add the image however: https://imgur.com/a/IbDdWIf

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine use all the links properly like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  

  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<b>Tooltip</b> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>">1</span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, but that doesn't work on my side and I definitely don't know why... I've abandoned the HTML tip anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: @goguinhus182 can you share your code here what you have tried